# how to write below select * from MYTABLE where date(MYDATE) between '2015-12-30' and '2015-12-30'; in JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

how to write below SQL:

```
select * from MYTABLE where date(MYDATE) between '2015-12-30' 
and '2015-12-30';
```

in JOOQ where MYDATE is type of java.sql.timestamp.

Comment: Why was this downvoted and closed as unclear? Seems very clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a 1:1 translation:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select()
   .from(MYTABLE)
   .where(DSL.date(MYTABLE.MYDATE).between(Date.valueOf("2015-12-30"))
                                  .and(Date.valueOf("2015-12-30")))
   .fetch();
```

Some criticism:

- Your two dates are the same, so your query might not really make sense
- You shouldn't cast/convert the `MYDATE` column, as this will prevent using indexes. Instead, you should work out the correct timestamp range for the two dates.

Comment: Thanks Lukas ! that's what I am looking for.